# Access element in the next adjacent table using index

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and I am trying to accomplish something that I have not found an answer.
I have two adjacent tables with the exact same # of rows and columns. When I click on an element in one table, I want to access the same element in the other table. So far, I can figure out what row index I am in the current table but I can't seem to go to the next table. Here is the layout of my table:

table1

```
row col1 col2
1    a    b 
2    c    d
3    e    f
```

table2

```
row col1 col2
1    w    x
2    y    z
3    n    m
```

For example, If I click "a" in table 1, I want to know what is the value in the element "w". I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make each table element have an id, where that id is something along the lines of 
"{tableNum}-{row}-{col}".  This would make it easy to access each element by its id.

If you were to see that a had been clicked, you would get back that element and access the element in the other table using `$("#table2-1-1")`.  Let me know if I worded this poorly.

Comment: That's where I have my problem. Since my tables are dynamically generated, both tables have the same name $("#gv"). Both elements "a" and "w" are named "Price". They are only differentiated in the clientID.

Comment: So each table corresponds to a different client?  then use the clientID in your id's.  So instead of `id={tableNum}-{row}-{col}`, use `id="{clientID}-Price"`.  I'm assuming each element is named something different in this case, so a and w are both price, but b and x are inventory or whatever

Comment: I was able to make the id of each table unique as you originally suggested. I just append a number for each table created (table0, table1, etc...). From there, I was able to access the tables and go to the specific row in each table to perform the calculation. Thanks.